# Longtable and rowcolor issue

Tags: longtable, rowcolor

The following is a `mwe` highlighting the issue of an extra white space in the header of a `longtable` I am working on. This occurs primarily due to `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` if I am not mistaken.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries Unit\ \arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}%
\setlength\LTright{0pt}%
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8.5em}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth}|p{6.5em}|@{}}
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endhead
    %\hline
    %--------------------------------------------- Week 1-3 ---------------------------------------------
    text 
    & 
    text
    &
    text
    & 
    text\tabularnewline
    \hline%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on how to remove that white space or at least what causes it?

Comment: white spaces are caused by `@{\extracolsep{\fill}`. don't use it. see, if `ltablex` is acceptable. in `tabularx` you not need to stretch columns apart.

Comment: @Zarko I don't mind other solutions, but I am also interested in a fix for the current issue.

Comment: as far as know,there is not other fix as don't use such approach to stretching table to text width. in your case (maybe i'm wrong) is only way to redefine column width such, that the table width become equal text width. in this you can use `\dimexpr`, consider `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`. i'm pretty sure, that such solution you can find on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see, if the following solution is fine to you:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, % only for see if table width fit text width               
           letterpaper,
           tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries Unit\ \arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                  |>{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                  |>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                  | p{\dimexpr0.2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endhead
    text
    &
    text
    &
    text
    &
    text\tabularnewline
    \hline%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

i didn't bother with exact recalculating of columns' widths, but this should not be a big deal :)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a longtable exactly `\textwidth`wide, I suggest you load `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I took the liberty to simplify your preamble, in particular you don't have to  load `array`,`longtable` nor `tabularx` since `ltablex` does it for you :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2.5cm, hmargin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,ltablex}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries Unit\ \arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8.5em}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|p{6.5em}|@{}}
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!10}\textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}\tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \endhead
    %\hline
    %--------------------------------------------- Week 1-3 ---------------------------------------------
    text
    &
    text
    &
    text
    &
    text \\
    \hline%
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks. I will explore your solution a bit more.

Comment: @azetina: The main interest of tabularx is you don't have to make  width computations yourself.

Comment: I agree. Duly noted. Am still old fashioned :)